# Post Loop Missing Most Recent Post

Tags: posts, loop, get-posts

I could use some help with a post loop that seems to always be missing the most recent post. I'm guessing that my loop is somehow buggy.

My code is below. Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php $posts = get_posts( "category=37" ); ?>
<?php if( $posts ) : ?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
  <div class="team-member">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><img src="<?php
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
    echo $feat_image;
    ?>" /></a>
    <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h3>
    <h3 class="homepage-post-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_content; ?></a></h3>
    <a class="read-more-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">Read More</a>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: by chance that post is a sticky post? `get_posts` has this "talent" to ignore sticky posts

Comment: is the latest post in category 37?

Comment: Yep, all of the posts are in category 37 and none of them are stickied. There should be eight posts showing and only 5 are being shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify `posts_per_page` in your [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) you will get the default amount of posts, which is five.

Normally the offset is 0 and order is by date, so this doesn't explain why the most recent post would be missing.